# Determining size of substring

Tags: c

I have a pointer to the begin of the string `char * input_buffer`, another pointer inside in this string `char * restP`. I have also the whole length of the string `ssize_t size`.

This String is not NULL-terminated.

How can I get the size between the  `restP` and the the end of the string?

Comment: Pointer subtraction?

Comment: @user897237 Curious as why you selected type `ssize_t` (not a C standard type, but maybe a Unix one) and not C standard types `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the length to restP using pointer subtraction (`restP - input_buffer`), so the length from restP to the end of the string is `size - (restP - input_buffer)`

Comment: Or, put another way, `input_buffer + size` is the end of the string, so `input_buffer+size - restP` naturally yields the distance from `restP` to to the end of the string. <:D

Answer (score -2):

I didnt reed that u dont have the null terminate
so you could do something like this:

```
size - (restP - input_buffer)
```

(if size is the end that you know of your string)

Comment: The OP doesn't have null-terminated strings, so `strlen` is not helpful.